# Swift 3: How to delete the single record in the Core Data when a UIbutton is Pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

I have a function, where I can add the Profile to the favourite list (which saves through Core Data) and when I want to mark it as Not Favourite, it should delete from the Core data and also from the TableList View (Favourite View Controller).

The code what I have so far, deletes all the records from the list instead deleting the specific record.

Please Find the code Below:-

```
 @IBAction func saveFav(_ sender: UIButton) {

   let propertyToCheck = sender.currentTitle!
    var proID = saved_id
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let task = FavProfile(context: context)

    switch propertyToCheck {
    case "Add to Favourite":
     // Link Task & Context
    task.busName = bussinessName
    task.profileID = Int32(id!)!
    print ("saved id is: - \(task.profileID)")
    print ("saved profile name is: - \(task.busName)")
    fav_remove_fav_button_label.setTitle("Remove From Favourite", for: .normal)

    // Save the data to coredata
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Added to your Favourite list", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        case "Remove from Favourite":



            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FavProfile")
            let moc = getContext()
            let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let resultData = result as! [FavProfile]

            for object in resultData {
                moc.delete(object)
            }

            do {
                try moc.save()
                print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {

            }




        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Removed from your Favourite list", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      //  self.favtable.tableView.reloadData()


    default: break
    }
}
```

I dont know what I need to fix here that only deletes the specific record.

Thanks for the time and effort.

Screen 1, when i mark the profile as favourite:

[image]

Screen 2 when i mark same profile as not favourite :

[image]

screen 3, when i restart the app again:

[image]

I tried to mark the 2nd profile as not favourite, it does not update the tableview. and when i restart the app, it shows "Label"

Comment: You have used a for loop to delete all fetched objects. You must use a predicate to fetch only the concerned object and then delete it.

Comment: @PuneetSharma I am new to coredata, so how do we remove the loop?

Comment: Fetch the specific FavProfile entity using the property profileID, if it is unique that is, and then delete it from context. To learn how to fetch specific  entity using NSPredicate, read this:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FavProfile")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "profileID == %@", id as CVarArg)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let moc = getContext()
    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultData = result as! [FavProfile]

    for object in resultData {
        moc.delete(object)
    }

    do {
        try moc.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

use predicate for profileID.

Comment: its working and does the required function. But I think there is still some small issue. When i add the profile to the favourite and then when i mark the same profile as not favourite, my favourite viewcontroller still shows the profile, until till unless i restart the app again. And when i restart the app, the profile name is gone from the cell and in stead the name changes to Label. Please refer to the screenshot

Comment: You should refetch the data from DB after deletion and then reload tableview. Try it.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but still I am not able to reload the table view

Comment: Can you give me the files if possible for you. I'll fix that.

Comment: sure, how do i send you the files?

Comment: Upload somewhere like on dropbox and give me the link.

Comment: do u have an gmail account?

Comment: Please let me know once you download it so that i can delete from this log

Comment: Got it. You can delete now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150564/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-ada).

Answer (score 0):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@ AND type == %@", "your target name","your target type")
            var fetchedEntities = [TrackTable]()
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TrackTable")
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            do {
                    fetchedEntities = try! managedContext?.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [TrackTable]
                    for sequence in fetchedEntities
                    {
                        managedContext?.delete(sequence)
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
     }
```

In above predicate `name` and `type` are the your table entities by which you want to delete particular entity.

Comment: i tried this suggestion but apparently it is giving me few errors

Answer (score -1):

```
* Add a Predicate Like given below to search for a particular item from the list of Favourites using it's unique profile Id. Search for that item in it's entity and delete that item from core data.
*****************************************
let predicateFavs = NSPredicate(format: “profileID = %@", String(describing: id!))
    let favList = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.fetchEntityWithName(“FavProfile”, predicate: predicateFavs) as! [FavProfile]

    context.performAndWait({
    for object in favList{
    self.context.delete(object)
    }

    do {
    try self.context.save()

    } catch {
    print("error : \(error)")
    }
    })


********************************************   



    func fetchEntityWithName(_ entityName : NSString, predicate: NSPredicate) -> NSArray{

        // Create Entity Description
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName as String, in: context)
        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        var result = NSArray()
        do {
            result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
            print(result)

        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
        }

        return result
    }
```